# Raspberry pi zero + Arduino Lilypad

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, lilypad

I was hoping to make a gesture+flex sensor controlled glove using an Arduino Lilypad and Raspberry Pi Zero W.

I was wondering how I could connect the two boards to communicate between them?

This is so I can take the flex sensor/accelerometer outputs, play with them in python, then send data over wifi to my pc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry pi and lillypad both have logic-level UARTs, that's probably the easiest way.

If you're running the lillypad from 5V you'll need a logic level converter for the interface with the 3.3v UART on the raspberry pi

SPI is also an option, but again you'll need a level converter.

Some lillypads have USB if yours is one of them then that'd work too

Comment: Thanks Jasen, if I connect the raspberry pi to the Lilypad via USB-MicroUSB, will that supply 5V current? And can they communicate through the USB port?

Comment: some lillypads have USB if yours is one of them then that'd work too (edit)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to grab the input that is coming through the USB port on the RPi? *EDIT**I will ask stackoverflow if you consider this a programming question*

Comment: `/dev/ttyUSB0` probably. or ask on "rasp-berry pi".